# Unable to retrieve links off google search results page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab all *relevant* links that show up on the results page for any given query using bs4, and then open them up on a new window.

The problem is, I'm not getting the relevant links. For any given query, my script returns links to things like gmail, google images, etc -- not links relevant to the query.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import webbrowser as wb
import requests 
import bs4 as bs



search=input()
url="https://www.google.ae/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=mgSoWKmWO-aG7gTgmJ2QDA&gws_rd=ssl#q="+search
#print(url)
user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

#headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'

req=requests.get(url,headers=user_agent)
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
print(req.status_code)
count=0
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    print(link.get("href"))
    if search in link.text:
        wb.open(link.get("href"))
```

I tried changing my user-agent to a really old one in the hopes that google might revert to html, but no such luck with that.

I know it it's possible to retrieve links with the google search API, but I'm curious to know if there's any way I can get the job done with bs4 instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`google`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google) package which gives intuitive access to the search results of google.

```
from google import search
for result in search('example'):
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

It was returning random links because you were extracting *all* `<a>` tags from HTML in a `for` loop:

```py
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
   # returns all <a> tags from the HTML
```

Instead, you're looking for this specific `<a>` tag from the "organic results part" in the HTML:

```py
# container with needed data
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):

  # extracting title from container above
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text

  # extracting link from container above
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
```

Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",    # query
  "gl": "us",                                  # country to search from
  "hl": "en",                                  # language
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(title, link, sep='\n')

-----------
'''
Samurai Cop - He speaks fluent Japanese - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTW3wOyIYw
Samurai Cop - What does "katana" mean? - Quotes.net
https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1060647
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to deal with such problems since it's done for the end-user, and pretty much the only thing that needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()


for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['title'])
  print(result['link'])

-----------
'''
Samurai Cop - He speaks fluent Japanese - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTW3wOyIYw
Samurai Cop - What does "katana" mean? - Quotes.net
https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1060647
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.